# Entry translation differences Craft 2 and Craft 3

Tags: localization, multi-site

In the middle of a Craft 3 build and the client has requested locales like their Craft 2 multilingual site. I am confused by Craft 3 localisation.
It appears I have to add a site as a language before I can localise/translate any content?

In Craft 2 the adding of translated content could be done directly in the entry via the panel above the slug field - here all the locales for Craft 2 would appear. (On the right in desktop use)

But despite options of Translation method, site, group, language the old method of swapping between entry content language within the entry on the right hand panel is not there. This makes it difficult to see / swap to what has been translated.  It appears changing language is done in the list view of entries. Am I missing something :( ?

Here is a shot of Craft 2: 
[image: craft 2 translation UI]

Here is a shot of Craft 3:
[image: craft3 language UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It appears I have to add a site as a language before I can localise/translate any content?

Yes. If you want to add a new language, you have to add a new site in Craft 3.

> It appears changing language is done in the list view of entries.

Changing the language is a matter of changing the site, which is done via the site dropdown in your 2nd screenshot.

Relevant docs:

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/sites.html

https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/localization.html

If you have suggestions for enhancements/improvements, feel free to share them here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues